# Remove Iterator from type typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a type which looks like this:

```js
export type PostFindManyOutput = inferQueryOutput<"post.findMany">;

// the type looks like this after being imported:
type PostFindManyOutput = {
    slug: string;
    title: string;
    excerpt: string;
    readTime: number;
    createdAt: Date;
}[]
```

How can remove the fact that it's supposed to be an array? So ideally I'd like the type to look like this:

```js
type PostFindManyOutput = {
    slug: string;
    title: string;
    excerpt: string;
    readTime: number;
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

I tried something like this: `type TypeOfElement<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer R] ? R : never;` and this `PostFindManyOutput[0]` with no luck...

Comment: Try `type Result = PostFindManyOutput[number]`

Answer (score 0):

You are very close actually: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZ2AMQJYDsAmBZAhukAeQFdgxSoBeKAbwCgooEAbYgcwC4ngAnDNgNwMowVMGYQuSPukHCIADwDGEHmGBTe-IYx4RcmACqoAtpKjpiJgEaqdUJXtzAImAIIaoAEWcQhAXwBtAF06OlBIKABRBV5cJWA3Hh5cEABJFxMAHkMoRRcsBChidABrdDgAd3QQgD4qKFz8iEKoAAoMADNVKABVAEoQqAB+PqgudAgANztw8Gg3Bul+ELnIgCEGmLiEpJT0zKy3WroAelOoTa7VPUwoXCLl2TXoAGEt2JTd5NSMiGz4Eg0Fg8AQSGRSCdzlB3tdkq57o9+BIoODyMAgA)

You can extract Array elements with the util of this block: `ExtractArrayItem`

```ts
type PostFindManyOutput = {
  slug: string;
  title: string;
  excerpt: string;
  readTime: number;
  createdAt: Date;
}[]

type ExtractArrayItem<T extends unknown[]> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;
type A = string[]
type B = ExtractArrayItem<A>
// B inferred as string
type C = ExtractArrayItem<PostFindManyOutput>
// C inferred as single Output
```

Edit: You could also use `PostFindManyOutput[number]` as [@captain-yossarian from Ukraine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian-from-ukraine) mentioned in the comments